# React : Cannot update during an existing state transition error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function which generatesTimelist for me. When it starts rendering the method should be called and the state displayed. It gets displayed, but the console is throwing multiple errors of:

```
setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.
```

My code looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


export default class Timeline extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(); 
            this.state = {
                timeList: 'aa'
            };
        }


      generateTimelineArray(start = 1499162400, end = 1499248800, step = 60) {
      let arr =[];
      for(let i = start; i <= end;i+=step) {
        const date = new Date(i);
        const hours = date.getHours();
        const mins = date.getMinutes();
        arr[i] = {
          time: hours + ":" + mins,
          hour: hours,
          minutes: mins
        };
      } 
    this.setState({ timeList: 'bb'});
        this.setState({ timeList: 'bb'});

    }


  render() {


{this.generateTimelineArray()}
    return (
      <div className="App" >
       {this.state.timeList}
      </div>
    ); 
  }
}
```

The generateTimelineArray is looping trough the specified arguments and creating an array. Which i later on want to map into another component, for example purposes i changed it to a string.

What is the cause of the error and how should this be fixed ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't call `this.setState` within a `render` cycle, just as the error has told you. Why not instead call the `generateTimelineArray` in the `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle `function` provided by `React`? Or perhaps during the `componentWillMount` function if you don't see the state of it changing.

This is a better place to 'react' to changes in state and as such build new component state. Ultimately you would end up in a a never ending loop because you would constantly be rendering and resetting the component state

[Facebook Documentation on React Lifecycle - `componentWillReceiveProps`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops)

Comment: There has to be arguments that are dynamic, in this case i have provided them hardcoded, but how should I send them to componentWillReceiveProps ?

Comment: If there are arguments that are dynamic, then you provide them to the `props` of this component in question:

`<Timeline timeLineProp={'prop1'} />` Changing `timeLineProp` it will trigger  `componentWillReceiveProps`

Comment: Ok, this sounds reasonable, so I got rid of the error but the state was not updated. https://pastebin.com/pVv0nvDf

Comment: Are you sure? Have you put a `console.log` there to see if the willReceiveProps is being hit when you change the props? Also you can access the next values via the `nextProps` argument, and can compare them to `this.props`

Comment: You han see live example here : https://codesandbox.io/s/7635yyGBw. It seems like setState is not getting triggered at all.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/31pZMR8Q

I have updated it. See how I have a parent component changing the props, and passing in a fresh value? That then hits the willReceiveProps...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148534/discussion-between-giedrius-and-glitch100).

Comment: Thans great but as i mentioned -"The generateTimelineArray is looping trough the specified arguments and creating an array. Which i later on want to map into another component". I have to somehow to initialize the creating arrow function and pass the array, still cannot see how to do that from your example :(