# React Native : Modify Component Level State with FlatList

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have two sections inside my main component. One section holds a FlatList and the other one displays the summation of a value in the object that FlatList receives.
My main components looks like so:

```
return (
  <View>
  <FlatList
    data={[{a:1,b:2},{a:3,b:4}]}
    renderItem={({item})=><View>{item.a}</View>}
  />
  <View>**SUM OF a(i.e 1+3=4)**</View>
  </View>
)
```

I am not able to display the summation of all `a` inside my second view.
When I try to modify the internal state of the app using `this.setState({a: this.state.a + item.a})` inside `renderItem`, I get an error.

The other way that I thought would be helpful is by looping through the object and not using FlatList at all. But even in that case, I am not able to use `this.setState({a: this.state.a + item.a})` from within the vanilla javascript's `map` function.

Example:

```
const arr = [{a:1,b:2},{a:3,b:4}]
arr.map(e=>{
  return this.setState({a: this.state.a + e.a})
})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? Also, your `FlatList` doesn't have a closing tag. Is it missing in your actual code?

Comment: The error says "Cannot update during an existing state transition" Also, I have edited the question by adding the closing tag here. It isn't missing in the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I realized you are trying to sum all of the `a` elements instead of modifying all the a elements in an array.

You cannot use `setState` the way you are trying to in your `map`. First of all, you should never invoke it in a render method. You are causing a rerender every time you call `setState` which is likely causing the error.

To sum the `a` properties do something like this:

```
sumA(newArray) {
  const newA = newArray.reduce((a, b) => a + b, this.state.a || 0 )

  this.setState({ a: newA });
}
```

Comment: Two problems jump out here: 1) I am not initializing the state from within the component like you did. The object is received as a response from a get request. 2) I am trying to avoid another loop to simply sum all the `a` values from the object as I am already doing that to render the object in FlatList or map function. Re-rendering the same object would cause more memory utilization.

Comment: If you are calling `setState` in your render method, then that is causing your issue.https://stackoverflow.com/a/44954453/6938822